# (NAudio) How to use a buffer to play individual samples of changing audio waves in C#?

Tags: c#, audio, stream, naudio

I am writing a program that is supposed to imitate the "DCF77" signal to change the time of radio clocks.
For that to work, I have to play a sound continuously (without cracking sounds; seamlessly) using changing waves (changing volume levels).

I was told to use NAudio and a Buffer, which stores samples/1 sample, sends them/it to the sound card and requests more samples as needed.

But how do I implement this?

My current code has an array with 60 elements called bits, which is used to determine how the sound changes in every second.
This array is recalculated once a minute.

If you didn't know, the DCF77 Signal encodes binary information like this:
A 0 means that the first 0.1 seconds of every second are at about 15% volume of the normal level.
A 1 means the same, but for 0.2 seconds.

Now, I have a SineWaveProvider32 class:

```
class SineWaveProvider32 : WaveProvider32
{
    int sample;

    public SineWaveProvider32()
    {
        Frequency = 1000;
        Amplitude = 0.25f;
    }

    public float Frequency { get; set; }
    public float Amplitude { get; set; }

    public override int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int sampleCount)
    {
        int sampleRate = WaveFormat.SampleRate;

        for(int i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++)
        {
            buffer[i + offset] = (float)(Amplitude * Math.Sin((2 * Math.PI * sample * Frequency) / sampleRate));
            sample++;
            if(sample >= sampleRate)
            {
                sample = 0;
            }
        }

        return sampleCount;
    }
}
```

As well as a WaveOut object

```
WaveOut waveOut;
```

and the main code has this method:

```
void StartStopSineWave()
{
    if (waveOut == null)
    {
        var sineWaveProvider = new SineWaveProvider32();
        sineWaveProvider.SetWaveFormat(192000, 1);
        sineWaveProvider.Frequency = 1000;
        sineWaveProvider.Amplitude = 0.25f;
        waveOut = new WaveOut();
        waveOut.Init(sineWaveProvider);
        waveOut.Play();
    }
    else
    {
        waveOut.Stop();
        waveOut.Dispose();
        waveOut = null;
    }
}
```

Please note that I am relatively new to C#, and sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I couldn't find any useful information, or at least didn't understand it.

Edit: For anyone who may have this same problem, I solved it by having a constant sine wave be output and changing the volume in real time using

```
waveOut.Volume
```

I know this is not perfect, but it works for what I'm doing.